# Working Tree blank in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have this file test.txt saved as below:

[image]

I add another line of text to the file and save:

[image]

As it's been changed, it appears under Source Control:

[image]

It doesn't show the previous version on the right hand side, it just shows a blank file:

[image]

I can't work out why it's blank / how to get it to show the old version.

I've added the file using `git add usr/local/bin/test.txt`

I've tried committing and changing the file again but still get the same result.

I'm SSH'd into a digitalocean server.

Comment: do you have your workspace in `/usr/local.bin`

Comment: the workspace is in the root directory `/`

Comment: and you have a `/.git` folder, and a lot of entries in the `.gitignore`?